# How can we instantiate comparator while using it as an argument in sorting?

Tags: java, spring, comparator

Why we use new keyword before comparator while using it as a constructor in sorting as comparator is an interface so we cannot instantiate it?

```
Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
      return p1.getAge() - p2.getAge();
  }
});
```

Comment: Because that's the syntax for an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) which can be used for implementing interfaces as well.

Comment: So we can instantiate any interface directly using anonymous class?

Comment: @RishuTyagi Yes, we can instantiate any interface directly using anonymous class. See [the Java tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) doing exactly that. Bonus tip: We can define an interface locally as of Java 16+, a nice by-product of the work to implement the new [Records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) feature.

Comment: You can implement any interface or extend any non-final (and non-sealed, if using Java 17+) class via an anonymous class (assuming appropriately visible constructors and abstract methods in the latter's case). And note the `java.util.Comparator` interface has only one abstract method, which means you can also implement it via a lambda expression or method reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because this code does not instantiate `Comparator`. As you said, that's not possible.

Instead, it is syntax sugar. It's short for:

```
// Yes, you can define a class inside a method.
class $AutoGeneratedName implements Comparator<Person> {
  @Override public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
    return p1.getAge() - p2.getAge();
  }
}

Collections.sort(persons, new $AutoGeneratedName());
```

In other words, short for: Define a new class, which `implements` Comparator. Then, instantiate this class once right away. Resolve this entire expression as a reference to this newly created instance. This construct is called an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

---

CAREFUL - this code is bad.

20 years ago, that code was mostly fine, except for one detail: using `a - b` in comparisons is dangerous for very large numbers, but presumably, given that this is about 'age', not going to be an issue. Still, bad form; `return Integer.comparing(p1.getAge(), p2.getAge())` would be much better.

But since then, this is no longer needed. You can write the concept much shorter like so:

```
Collections.sort(persons, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.getAge(), b.getAge());
```

We can do even that much, much simpler, and more readably by using [`List#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) with [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)).

```
persons.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));
```

which does exactly what you think it does when you just read it like its english: It sorts the collection 'persons' by comparing a specific int - which int? The one you get when you invoke `getAge()` on the person method.

This last snippet is what you should be using instead.

Comment: So according to this we can create classes inline which implements the interface for existing interface without giving them a name?

Comment: @RishuTyagi Yes, see [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)